# Get friends email addresses from twitter

Tags: twitter

I want to implement a contact import function that enables my website to import users contacts from twitter by retrieving their twitter friends firstname,lastname, and email address.
Is there any way to do that?

I have checked the api :

```
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list
```

but it dont give email id of friends.
Please help.
thanks